# Increase the gap between TableView sections?

Tags: ios6, uitableview, height

Is it possible to increase the gap between TableView sections?

I have two sections that are grouped and I want to add a segment controller in between two sections. I've got the segment controller in the area I want it but I need the second section to start further down, can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either put an additional section in the table to hold the segment or add a section header view to the section below the segment.  Just provide an empty view for the header. Implement the `heightForSectionHeader...` method so the height comes out as needed.

Comment: I dragged the segment onto the storyboard....having said that does adding a section in the middle mean I can programatically create the segment without using the storyboard? As I use dynamic cells the cells I create only appear at runtime.

Comment: You can do everything in code. Storyboards (and Interface Builder) are completely optional.

Comment: Thanks maddy and the heightForSection worked nicely. I'll look into creating the segment in code but I do have it positioned how I'd like it using storyboard. Thanks again